# Restore Default Form Submit thru Button/type='submit' behaviour

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a button in the jquery mobile form, which defines the post action attributes.

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false" method="POST" target="uploadTarget" action="https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token="...">

<input id="source" name="source" type="file">
<input id="message" name="message" type="text">

<button id="upload" type="submit" name="upload">Upload Photo</button>
</form>
```

The post method on the form is not called when I click on the styled button.

The method 'post' is called on the form if I use **data-role="none"**

```
<button data-role="none" id="upload" type="submit" name="upload">Upload Photo</button>
```

But the button obviously loses the mobile styles.

I have data-ajax="false" at the form level as shown (thanks to CBroe!) , but that does not help.

Is there any option to get the jquery mobile styles on buttons, but leave the default Form events and submit/post behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have already tried to data-ajax="false", but that does not help.

Where did you put that – on the button element, or on the form element? (It’s supposed to be set on the form.)

Comment: I had it on the button. But then I moved it to the form and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mobile css file. I was using an older version. after including the latest version :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
```

It seems to work.